# Applying row over row conditional logic in aggregate functions in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables stored in a MySQL database.  The first contains pricing information about SKUs I want to sell tomorrow.  The second contains historical sales and visitation data for SKUs. What I want to do is calculate the conversion rate (orders divided by visits) for each SKU at the price specified in the tomorrow's pricing table based on prior sales data at tomorrow's specified price, conditioned that the SKU at that price has at least 100 visits OR 50 visits and 1 order, and if not then I want it to add the visits and orders from the next highest price point.

I've created a table containing example data in an SQL fiddle

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf4273

Using the example data in the sqlfiddle, what I want to return then would be

```
ABC1, 100.0, 100, 0
ABC2, 75.0, 24, 0
ABC3, 35.0, 1312, 57
ABC4, 190, 55, 1
ABC5, 250, 72, 1
ABC6, 250.0, 80, 1
```

If you examine the data in the sql fiddle, you can see that ABC1 doesn't meet the count requirements at the specified $100 price point, so it rolls up the visits from the next higher price point, in that case 110, but keeps the reported price at 100.

ABC2 doesn't have enough visits at the specified price, but there aren't any visits at any other price point higher than the specified one, so it just returns the 24 and 0 visits.

ABC3 meets the requirements, so it just returns the specified value

ABC4 meets the > 50 visits and > 1 sale, so it's returned

ABC5 doesn't have enough visits and orders at the specified price, so it sums up the visits and orders to include the next highest price point. This logic is re-applied again if rolling up to the next highest price point still doesn't meet the requirements for 100 visits or 50 visits and 1 order.

ABC6 is similar to ABC5 except that now the orders at the specified price point for ABC6 for tomorrow is zero, but we still take the orders count from the next highest price point too (e.g. we sum up visits and orders from the next highest price point until we meet the necessary visits and/or orders requirements).

At the moment I've applied this logic inside Python, but it's a bit cumbersome and if possible I'd like to have it all in SQL.  Can anyone help?  Even telling me it's not possible to do this in MySQL would be valued.

Thanks,
Brad

Comment: Could you add some expected data to your question?

Comment: I did, or I thought I did.  I specified six lines above, one for each SKU, showing the SKU, price point, visits, and orders.

Comment: I'm not trying to be snarky here, I'm just not clear on what is being sought out.

Comment: Well I am a little confused with your description : In your example, can you precise if you search results with respectively `WHERE temp_table.visits > 50 AND temp_table.price >= prices.price` so that the result for ABC1 would be `ABC1, 100.0, 100, 0` ? I see you have a lot more criteria, but within the request itself. This may need some `MIN (temp_table.price; prices.price) as price`. Can you specify the specific list of criteria (as values or variables) ? You will need some `JOIN` in your request too, but I'm needing some precision first

Comment: My bad, Php confusion, MIN can't be used that way, it's a IF statement : `IF (temp_table.price < prices.price, temp_table.price, prices.price) as price`. You do not have the exact same number of SKU in your price table, I guess it's only for the example ?

Comment: Hey, yeah, it's just an example.  I can't post real data, there would be too much of it and it's sensitive.  I'll edit the post and try to increase the clarity.